# count words from list in another list in entry one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

Hy, 
I want to count given phrases from a list in another list on position zero.

```
list_given_atoms= ['C', 'Cl', 'Br']
list_of_molecules= ['C(B2Br)[Cl{H]Cl}P' ,'NAME']
```

When python find a match it should be safed in a dictionary like

```
countdict = [ 'Cl : 2', 'C : 1', 'Br : 1']
```

i tried

```
re.findall(r'\w+', list_of_molecules[0])
```

already but that resulsts in words like "B2Br", which is definitly not what i want.

can someone help me?

Comment: *in a dictionary* - but your `countdict` is a list

Answer (score 1):

`[a-zA-Z]+` should be used instead of `\w+` because `\w+` will match both letters and numbers, while you are just looking for letters:

```
import re
list_given_atoms= ['C', 'Cl', 'Br']
list_of_molecules= ['C(B2Br)[Cl{H]Cl}P' ,'NAME']
molecules = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', list_of_molecules[0])
final_data = {i:molecules.count(i) for i in list_given_atoms}
```

Output:

```
{'C': 1, 'Br': 1, 'Cl': 2}
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I would change the regex to `r'[A-Z][a-z]?'` since you're always going to get a capital letter and an optional lowercase letter.

Comment: @BrettBeatty regarding the regex, `[a-zA-Z]` will cover any occurrences, in any order. Thus, it actually does not matter.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the original string always has something between atom names. I was thinking you could end up with an occurrence of something like `'HCl'`.

Comment: @BrettBeatty `[a-zA-Z]` should work on that example as well, although is `r'[A-Z][a-z]?'` is certainly thorough.

Comment: This fails for the case where a molecule was something like `CO2` as it will give just one atom as `CO` whereas it should give two atoms: `C` and `O`

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
>>> Counter(re.findall('|'.join(sorted(list_given_atoms, key=len, reverse=True)), list_of_molecules[0]))
Counter({'Cl': 2, 'C': 1, 'Br': 1})
```

You have to sort the elements by their length, so `'Cl'` matches before `'C'`.

Answer (score 0):

Short `re.findall()` solution:

```
import re

list_given_atoms = ['C', 'Cl', 'Br']
list_of_molecules = ['C(B2Br)[Cl{H]Cl}P' ,'NAME']
d = { a: len(re.findall(r'' + a + '(?=[^a-z]|$)', list_of_molecules[0], re.I)) 
      for a in list_given_atoms }

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'C': 1, 'Cl': 2, 'Br': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solutions and i figured out, that there are also several C after each other. So I came to this one here:

```
for element in re.findall(r'([A-Z])([a-z|A-Z])?'. list_of_molecules[0]):
    if element[1].islower:
        counter = element[0] + element[1]
        if not (counter in counter_dict):
            counter_dict[counter] = 1
        else:
            counter_dict[counter] += 1
```

The same way I checked for elements with just one case and added them to the dictionary. There is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `/w` as a word character is equivalent to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

which clearly includes numbers so therefore `"B2Br"` is matched.

You also can't just use the regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

as that would produce one atom for something like `"CO2"`which should produce `2` separate molecules: `C` and `0`.

---

However the regex I came up with ([`regex101`](https://regex101.com/r/xdyG2P/1)) just checks for a capital letter and then between `0` and `1` (so optional) lower case letter.

Here it is:

```
[A-Z][a-z]{0,1}
```

and it will correctly produce the atoms.

---

So to incorporate this into your original `lists` of:

```
list_given_atoms= ['C', 'Cl', 'Br']
list_of_molecules= ['C(B2Br)[Cl{H]Cl}P' ,'NAME']
```

we want to first find all the atoms in `list_of_molecules` and then create a dictionary of the counts of the atoms in `list_given_atoms`.

So to find all the atoms, we can use `re.findall` on the first element in the molecules list:

```
atoms = re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]{0,1}", list_of_molecules[0])
```

which gives a `list`:

```
['C', 'B', 'Br', 'Cl', 'H', 'Cl', 'P']
```

then, to get the counts in a dictionary, we can use a `dictionary-comprehension`:

```
counts = {a: atoms.count(a) for a in list_given_atoms}
```

which gives the desired result of:

```
{'Cl': 2, 'C': 1, 'Br': 1}
```

---

And would also work when we have molecules like `CO2` etc.